# how to grab data from an array of checkboxes in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have a form of check boxes that are in sync with my data base column questions.  I out put the checked boxes and it gives me the output Array([0]=>) rather then the question. I feel like i should be using id and question somehow when i grab the data.

```
 echo '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="'.$row["ID"].'">' . $row["Question"]." <br />";
```

to grab it on next page

```
 print_r($_POST['checkbox']);
```

Comment: Only checked checkboxes send data to the next page.

Comment: if you want to show the non-checked check boxes in POST request, you'll have to use AJAX

Comment: yea i want to see the checked boxes.

Comment: is there any other way out put database rows with a checkbox for each then displayed the checked information? because this is getting ugly

Comment: You can place the id of your record inside the braces: `name="checkbox[123]"` – that way, you will get an array with the ids as keys for the checked checkboxes. If you need to transport a specific value together with that id, put it into the `value` attribute.